# AWS Cognito token with custom claims based on authorization context

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to call initiate_auth, using the ClientMetadata parameter to pass contextual data that I want included as custom claims in the identity token that I get back. I thought that I could access the ClientMetaData in a pre-token-generation trigger, and use it to generate the extra claims.  Unfortunately, CLientMetaData, while available to a pre-authentication trigger, is not available to the pre-token-generation trigger.

Any suggestions?

Background:  The scenario involves a mix of AWS functionality and legacy, non-AWS functionality.  The end user in a browser has a authenticated session with the legacy application.  End users do not have cognito accounts.  I want the legacy back end to call cognito using client credentials (service credentials) to get a token that includes, in its custom claims, information that identifies the end user.

Comment: I had seen a similar issue and I think there's a feature request for this.

Comment: Workaround: Save metadata to DynamoDb in Pre-Auth trigger. Retrieve the same in Pre-Token Gen. trigger and clean DDB entry. Haven't tested it & am not sure if it'll work and if it does whether it affects the performance.

Comment: @agent420, yeah, I had the same idea, but there's no common key.  The RequestId is a different value in the two triggers.